# Failing to use LAPACK functions (cgeev function) in MATLAB mex codes

Tags: c, matlab, mex

I've been trying to use cgeev function in my MATLAB mex code to compute eigenvalues and eigenvectors of (skew-symmetric) complex matrix but ended up failing so far.

Here is the code I wrote.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

/* Macro to define the correct function prototype */
#if defined (_WIN32) || defined(__APPLE__)
#define FORTRAN_COMPLEX_FUNCTIONS_RETURN_VOID 1
#endif

#include "mex.h"
#include "blas.h"
#include "lapack.h"
#include "fort.h"    /* defines complex data handling functions */

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    if(nrhs != 1)
        mexErrMsgTxt("Only one input argument is allowed.");
    else if(nlhs > 3)
        mexErrMsgTxt("Too many output arguments.");

    const mxArray *X = prhs[0];

    size_t n = mxGetM(X);
    size_t two_n = 2 * n;
    size_t one = 1;

    mxArray *D = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(n, one, mxCOMPLEX);
    mxArray *VL = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(n, n, mxCOMPLEX);
    mxArray *VR = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(n, n, mxCOMPLEX);

    double *Dfort = mat2fort(D, n, one);
    double *VLfort = mat2fort(VL, n, n);
    double *VRfort = mat2fort(VR, n, n);
    double *Xfort = mat2fort(X, n, n);

    char *jobvlr = 'V';

    mxArray *LWORK = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(one, two_n, mxCOMPLEX);
    double *LWORKfort = mat2fort(LWORK, two_n, two_n);
    mxArray *RWORK = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(one, two_n, mxREAL);
    double* RWORKfort = mat2fort(RWORK, one, two_n);
    int INFO = 0;

    /* call BLAS function */
    cgeev_(jobvlr, jobvlr, &n, Xfort, &n, Dfort, VLfort, &n, VRfort, &n,
           LWORKfort, &two_n, RWORKfort, &INFO);

    plhs[0] = fort2mat(VLfort, n, n, n);
    plhs[1] = fort2mat(Dfort, n, n, one);
    plhs[2] = fort2mat(VRfort, n, n, n);

    mxDestroyArray(D);
    mxDestroyArray(VL);
    mxDestroyArray(VR);
    mxDestroyArray(LWORK);
    mxFree(LWORKfort);
    mxDestroyArray(RWORK);
    mxFree(RWORKfort);
    mxFree(Xfort);

    return;
}
```

This code is compilable in my environment (Macbook pro with High Sierra and MATLAB 2017a), but once I execute the compiled function it crashes without any error message (That is a typical behavior of MATLAB when we execute mex codes with segmentation fault kind of bugs). When I comment out the cgeev_ function call lines, it is also compilable and now executable without any errors. So I think there are some mistakes in the usage of LAPACK functions in my code.

I also tried to compile a matrix multiplication code with LAPACK which is provided by Mathworks as below. I succeeded to compile and execute it.

```
copyfile(fullfile(matlabroot,'extern','examples','refbook','matrixMultiply.c'),'.')
```

Would anyone have suggestions or helps for identifying the actual mistakes in my code?

**Postscript**

I resolved this issue by myself in the end. The problem of my first code was my misunderstandings of the specifications of the clapack functions. cgeev_ and zgeev_ functions receive "complex" or "doublecomplex" type variables, which are defined in "f2c.h" for specific use of lapack functions from c codes. "fort.h" header provided by Mathworks doesn't contain utility functions for such data types (they may provide some other functions that I don't know for clapack usage). So I needed to write my own conversion functions from MATLAB matrices to complex arrays.
Here's the code I re-wrote.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

/* Macro to define the correct function prototype */
#if defined (_WIN32) || defined(__APPLE__)
#define FORTRAN_COMPLEX_FUNCTIONS_RETURN_VOID 1
#endif

#include "mex.h"
#include "blas.h"
#include "lapack.h"
#include "fort.h"    /* defines complex data handling functions */

doublecomplex* mat2clapack(const mxArray *X)
{
    int m =  (int)mxGetM(X);
    int n =  (int)mxGetN(X);
    doublecomplex *Z = (doublecomplex *)mxCalloc(m * n, sizeof(doublecomplex));
    double *xr = mxGetPr(X);
    doublecomplex *zp = Z;
    if(mxIsComplex(X)){
        double *xi = mxGetPi(X);
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                zp->r = *xr++;
                zp->i = *xi++;
                zp++;
            }
        }
    }else{
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                zp->r = *xr++;
                zp->i = 0.0;
                zp++;
            }
        }
    }
    return(Z);
}

mxArray* clapack2mat(doublecomplex *Z, mwSignedIndex m, mwSignedIndex n)
{
    mxArray *X = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(m, n, mxCOMPLEX);
    double *xr = mxGetPr(X);
    double *xi = mxGetPi(X);
    doublecomplex *zp = Z;
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            *xr++ = zp->r;
            *xi++ = zp->i;
            zp++;
        }
    }
    return(X);
}

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    if(nrhs != 1)
        mexErrMsgTxt("Only one input argument is allowed.");
    else if(nlhs > 3)
        mexErrMsgTxt("Too many output arguments.");

    const mxArray *X = prhs[0];

    mwSignedIndex n = mxGetM(X);
    mwSignedIndex two_n = 2 * n;
    mwSignedIndex one = 1;

    mxArray *D = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(n, one, mxCOMPLEX);
    mxArray *VL = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(n, n, mxCOMPLEX);
    mxArray *VR = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(n, n, mxCOMPLEX);

    doublecomplex *Dfort = mat2clapack(D);
    doublecomplex *VLfort = mat2clapack(VL);
    doublecomplex *VRfort = mat2clapack(VR);
    doublecomplex *Xfort = mat2clapack(X);

    char *jobvlr = "V";

    mxArray *LWORK = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(one, two_n, mxCOMPLEX);
    doublecomplex *LWORKfort = mat2clapack(LWORK);
    mxArray *RWORK = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(one, two_n, mxREAL);
    double* RWORKfort = mat2fort(RWORK, one, two_n);
    ptrdiff_t INFO = 0;

    /* call BLAS function */
    zgeev_(jobvlr, jobvlr, &n, Xfort, &n, Dfort, VLfort, &n, VRfort, &n,
           LWORKfort, &two_n, RWORKfort, &INFO);

    plhs[0] = clapack2mat(VLfort, n, n);
    plhs[1] = clapack2mat(Dfort, n, one);
    plhs[2] = clapack2mat(VRfort, n, n);

    mxDestroyArray(D);
    mxDestroyArray(VL);
    mxDestroyArray(VR);
    mxDestroyArray(LWORK);
    mxDestroyArray(RWORK);

    return;
}
```

I feel happy if this can help someone else.

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to use complex numbers with single precision (which is suggested by `c` prefix of `geev`) then I think you should declare so.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow Could you try `zgeev_` instead of `cgeev_` to use double precision complex? Coud you also try `char *jobvlr = "V";` and `&two_n,LWORKfort,  RWORKfort`? See http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-3.1.1-html/cgeev.f.html for the order of arguments.

Comment: Thank you guys for the help. I'm sorry for replying so late because I was really busy last week. 

>  percusse
Thank you. I've already tried single precision version of my code using "mxCreateNumericMatrix(n, one, mxSINGLE_CLASS, 1);" kind of codes instead of "mxCreateDoubleMatrix" in the code above but haven't succeeded yet (matlab crashed as the same as my original case).

Comment: > francis
Thank you. I didn't know the zgeev_ function! I haven't tested your suggestions yet but will work on it this week.